# Как исправить файл konfiguration.php в joomla

Tags: joomla, php

Недавно установил joomla на хостинг и всё бы ничего но файл konfiguration.php не сохраняет изменения, из-за этого куча проблем. Подскажите что делать?

Comment: может **configuration.php**

Comment: Не надо [плодить вопросы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/238684/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-konfiguration-php-%D0%B2-joomla)!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно дело в правах доступа к файлу. Посмотрите какие права стоят на configuration.php, должна быть возможность редактирования.
Минимально необходимые права на configuration.php для возможности редактирования владельцем - 644.